# How do Flink job managers get assigned when deployed in application mode?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

From https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/07/14/application-mode.html

Creating a cluster per application can be seen as creating a session cluster shared only among the jobs of a particular application and torn down when the application finishes.

Does each job has separate JM or shared? Image is showing something different, want to clarify on this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A Flink application can consist of multiple jobs/parts. When using the application mode, Flink deploys a dedicated cluster for an application. This cluster contains a `JobManager` process which will be used to run all jobs/parts of the Flink application. Hence, the process will be shared by the different parts of the application.

Comment: Ok, which means Job manager is shared same a session mode. Cool!! A leading question, does TaskManager/TMSlots also gets shared ? If so, can the figure be updated to depict this.

Comment: I think the picture is correct. There are multiple JMs, one for each application (indicated by the color). TMs won't be shared across different JMs/applications and that's why every TM runs tasks of only one color.

Comment: In Application mode, can a job of different applications can be present on the same cluster? Or the cluster depicted in the picture is an amalgamation of multiple applications running in application mode?

Comment: I think it is the latter. The yellow cloud is the cloud/resource management system (K8s, Yarn, Mesos, etc.) on which it runs and not the Flink cluster.

Comment: Thank for the answer. Missing clarity on does TMs of an application gets shared among jobs of the same application like session deployment modes? Can you please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

In application mode assumption is, an application is made up of multiple jobs. Each job will be isolated has separate Job Manager and Task manager (thus providing the same resource isolation and load balancing guarantees as the Per-Job Mode). Another different in application mode is main() method (pre-flight) is executed on Job manager instead of client.